# Can I close a pdf completely after viewing it in fullscreen?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to know if it is possible to make a PDF viewer close completely when hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> on the keyboard?

My problem is that I made a PowerPoint presentation and then link to some PDF that I would like to open in full screen and the close down when hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Comment: You forgot to mention what PDF viewer you're using.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> will close most programs on most OSs